# parsing text from HTML source

Tags: c#, text, types, ova

I have this Html (xml form) result in my program
[image: example]

All I want is get info from this source(director - music .....) 
is there any way to grouping text like 1 and 2 in picture with c# ?

Comment: It doesn't seems html..anyway you can parse HTML with http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest option you have is to use .Split. First I will split the entire source with the character { (this will give you your sections) and then I will .Split again each one of those sections with the character | From there you only need to parse what you need, you'll end up with an array of Name=Values.

Something like this will help:

```
var blocks = YourVariableHoldingSource.Split('{')
foreach(var block in blocks){
  var details = blocks.Split('|')    
  foreach(var data in details){
     MessageBox.Show(data);
  }
}
```